# What is the most efficient way of achieving all possible endings?

Tags: bioshock-2

I understand that in Bioshock 2 the game will have different endings based on your decisions to save or harvest little sisters.

Rather than replaying the game from scratch for each possible ending, I was thinking about getting to a point whereby all endings were still obtainable.  From this save, I could make copies for each of the path (therefore will only need to play part of the game, rather than the full game all over again).

How should I proceed to creating such a save?  I want to be as far into the game as possible and don't mind back tracking empty rooms to revisit sisters.

Is this even feasible?

Also, would it be possible to combine this save with collecting every single audio log?

In the end I want to saves for each of the endings (with all audio logs collected).  I will discard the "point of no return" save once all endings are achieved.

Answer (score 3):

[According to IGN](http://www.ign.com/wikis/bioshock-2/Secret_Endings), it is possible to achieve all 6 endings (3 main endings with 2 variations each) by playing most of the game only twice. You will need to save before you get to choose whether you want to kill or spare one of the following characters:

> Grace Holloway, Stanley Poole, and Gilbert Alexander

I'll refer to them as "VIP" from now on.

---

#### Playthrough 1: save all Little Sisters

In your first playthrough, you'll need to save all Little Sisters, and kill all of the VIP mentioned above; save before you kill the first one, and save before you kill the last one.

Once you've seen the first ending, load the latest save and spare the last VIP to get the other variation of the first ending.

#### Playthrough 2: save at least one Little Sister, and harvest at least one other

Load the first save (the one from before you killed the first VIP). You'll want to spare all the VIPs this time around. Save before you spare the last one, and save before you get to choose between Life or Death.

Load your previous save game and change your choice.

Load the second-latest save game, and change your choice. Remember to save before you make the last choice, so you can load that last save and change your choice for the last time.

Comment: Interesting, it says in the article that "You can deal with only one little sister or all of them to affect your ending", which makes it sound like you can deal with only 1 little sister (either harvest or save, leaving every other girl where they stand).

Comment: Yes, although I'd still try to deal with as many Little Sisters as possible, for the Adam.